# How do I translate this italian locution?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, translation, italian

Often in Italian we use this locution:

> venire meno

Now I wanted to translate it and I didn't come with an 'immediate' translation.

Somebody knows the English equivalent?

Comment: This is a site about English, not a translation site. Can you explain what _venire meno_ actually **means** and in what contexts it is used? Then maybe someone can think of an appropriate English equivalent. Also, have you tried looking in a dictionary before you asked here? If so, please include what you found in your question; as it stands now, it seems you have done nothing to find an answer before asking here, which means the question will probably be closed if not edited.

Comment: Ciao beppe - what does that mean ??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is mere translation, without giving a literal equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Background: I live in Italy, am a native American Standard English speaker, and speak conversational but grammatically-clumsy Italian. ;) ]*

However, this site makes sense to me: http://en.bab.la/dictionary/italian-english/venir-meno

As you can see from the site, "venir meno" is an Italian phraseology whose usage does not have single, simple, word-for-word translatability, as do most words, in English.

Comment: Grazie! I was hoping for an universal-use translation... :(

Comment: Would "fall shy of" or "fall short of" suffice in many circumstances.